JSON::SerializableError when deserializing PascalCased properties using JSON::Serializable in a Crystal app
I’m developing a Crystal application and consuming an API that inconsistently uses PascalCase for some of its endpoint properties, rather than camelCase. Unfortunately, this causes issues with JSON::Serializable, which doesn’t handle PascalCase properties smoothly. I’ve been able to successfully deserialize responses from other API endpoints using .from_json, as long as the properties follow the camelCase convention.
Parsing the response:
  api_url = "api.notmyapi.com"
  client = HTTP::Client.new(api_url)
  params = "/api?lets-get-some-pascal-case-i-guess"
  
  json_response = PascalCaseResponse.from_json(client.get(params).body)

  puts "json_response = #{json_response}" # No Bueno.

This works just fine on all of the other endpoints that have the proper camelCase naming convention.
However, here is what my Response class looks like, which is modeled directly after the structure of the JSON returned by the API...
class PascalCaseResponse
  include JSON::Serializable

  property PropertyOne : String
  property SomeOtherProperty : String

  ....

  property WhereAreTheCamels : String
end

... modeled after the structure of the API endpoint response:
  {
     "PropertyOne":"I am a String",
     "SomeOtherProperty":"So am I!",

     ....

     "WhereAreTheCamels":"I do not know"
  }

Which yields this exception:
/Users/tyler/Code/project  $ crystal build src/main.cr; ./main
In src/responses/someresponse.cr:37:23

 37 | property PropertyOne : String
                           ^
Error: unexpected token: ":"
Unhandled exception: Missing JSON attribute: PropertyOne

What makes me believe it's the PascalCase is that when I change it property to propertyOne, it goes down the line complaining about SomeOtherProperty, but ALSO about PropertyOne, which I find odd.
/Users/tyler/Code/project  $ crystal build src/main.cr; ./main
In src/responses/someresponse.cr:38:16

 38 | property SomeOtherProperty : String
                   ^
Error: unexpected token: ":"
Unhandled exception: Missing JSON attribute: PropertyOne

How do I tell JSON::Serializable to map the PascalCase JSON properties to my Response object that I obviously would like to keep camelCased?
I've tried
@[JSON::Field(key: "PascalCase")]
property camelCase: String

But that didn't work, and coming from a Kotlin/Java serialization background that seems like it would be the way to go.
Am I missing something?

PropertyOne is not a valid method name, hence the error you get. You could use propertyOne like you tried, but by convention Crystal method names are snake cased. You were on the right track using JSON::Field, but you'll have to do that for every property. Something like:
class PascalCaseResponse
  include JSON::Serializable

  @[JSON::Field(key: "PropertyOne")]
  property property_one : String

  @[JSON::Field(key: "SomeOtherProperty")]
  property some_other_property : String

  @[JSON::Field(key: "WhereAreTheCamels")]
  property where_are_the_camels : String
end

should do the trick.
